# Remote Desktop Application

Tags: vb.net, rdp

I'm trying to use 'Microsoft RDP Client Control verison 9', but it does not show any thing into the control on the form, here is my code

```
    axRDP.Server = "10.10.10.10"
    axRDP.UserName = "Domain\Username"

    Dim secured As IMsTscNonScriptable = DirectCast(axRDP.GetOcx(), IMsTscNonScriptable)
    secured.ClearTextPassword = "Password1"
    axRDP.Connect()
```

Please I want to know what is wrong with my code and how to resolve it.

Comment: Have you tried running your application as administrator, as per [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylorb/archive/2013/05/02/developing-a-custom-vmconnect-application.aspx#10424463)? (See comments below main article)

Comment: If you are using it from ASP.NET, then you might need to [enable the ActiveX control in IE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd701184(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: Running the application as an administrator did not resolve the issue

Comment: 1. Are you calling this code when the form is visible? I've had issues if the form hasn't been shown yet. 2. Do you have the appropriate apartment state set for the thread? The RDP ActiveX control requires the STA model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to right click on **toolbox** and select **choose items**

There go to COM tab and select and there you select 
**`Microsoft Terminal Services Client control`**

Now you'll find a remote desktop connection in your toolbox..Drag and drop on to your form

That's it :)

Comment: However I have seen the ActiveX control in my toolbox by now after your advise, I'm stuck with my code malfunctioning

Comment: can RDP used in a different Network on both Clients connected?